# EclipseLink Audit / History / Track changes

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, history, audit, changelog

i've tried to implement a way to track data changes and create a history log for my application. Because i'm using EclipseLink it should be easy and possible to get the changes like they [write on the EclipseLink FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_access_what_changed_in_an_object_or_transaction.3F)
The first solution works but the second event based won't work. Everytime the event is raised the ObjectChangeSet is null.

The reason why i'm not simply using HistoryPolicy is that i wan't to store information about the logged on user (not the db user) and the changed data to a separate table. I searched a lot but can't find any solution to this problem.

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(HistoryEventListener.class)
@Table(name = "t_users")
    public class Users implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GENSEQ_USERS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "GENSEQ_USERS", sequenceName = "SEQ_USERS", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
private Integer id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String userid;
...
}
```

And this is my DescriptorEventAdapter class:

```
public class HistoryEventListener extends DescriptorEventAdapter {

@Override
public void postUpdate(DescriptorEvent event) {
    ObjectChangeSet changeSet = event.getChangeSet();
    if (changeSet != null) {
        System.out.println("ObjectChangeSet not null");
    }
    System.out.println("ObjectChangeSet null");
}

@Override
public void postMerge(DescriptorEvent event) {
    ObjectChangeSet changeSet = event.getChangeSet();
    if (changeSet != null) {
        System.out.println("ObjectChangeSet not null");
    }
    System.out.println("ObjectChangeSet null");
}
}
```

The persistence.xml file which i've used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="PhoneBookPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@somehostname:1521:xyz"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="getyourown"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the change set is only set for the merge event, not the postUpdate.  Please log a bug to have the change sets added to the pre/postUpdate events.

You can also get the ChangeSet from the query or object,

```
((UpdateObjectQuery)event.getQuery()).getObjectChangeSet()
```

or,

```
((AttributeChangeListener)((ChangeTracker)event.getObject())._persistence_getPropertyChangeListener()).getObjectChangeSet()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Getting the ChangeSet from the query works inside postUpdate `if (event.getQuery() != null)`. But why is `event.getChangeSet()` null. It would be great if you can tell me your source so i can read more about it. I also read other posts about this but nobody posted his solution or a hint where you can read more about it.